# How to maintain the background image until end of the page

Tags: html, css

I have this short example:

**CODE CSS:**

```
 body{
background:url(DECUPATE/TEST/images/ppp.jpg);
bacground-size:contain;
backgoun-repeat:none;
}
```

I put a picture to understand what they want to do.

http://i61.tinypic.com/10xeeeb.jpg

if you put `background size: cover` appears to the end but there is the incomplet image.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use the jquery backstretch function .$.backstretch("Your_image_path");

Comment: How about `background-size:100%`?

Comment: background-size: 100% 100%;

Comment: Background size 100% stretches the resulting image  and in some cases image appears distorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use html instead of body ,see the code below :

```
html {
      background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: 100% 100% cover;
      -moz-background-size: 100% 100% cover;
      -o-background-size: 100% 100% cover;
      background-size: 100% 100% cover;
      /* set the padding and margin to "0" */
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
     /* set the position rules */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery plugin backstretch for this
this will allow background to stretch through out the screen. it also works well with  smaller screens.

http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

download backstrech js from the url given above and add it in your header tag .
initiate backstretch with following code in script tag

```
  $.backstretch("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example, for the most broad support :

```
 background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
```

https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of it as one background. Give your header and footer the background-img and set the header position to `background-position:center top` and your 'footer' position of `background-position:center bottom` additionally add the `background-size` property to 100% or cover. Since both elements have the same width the size property will have the same effect on both.

Answer (score 0):

Add the CSS code    `background-attachment:fixed;`
This will make the background stay the same if you scroll down.

Answer (score -1):

```
<body> <img src="images/ppp.jpg"> </body>

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body > img{
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;

        /*For IE*/
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }
```